Are there PDF files that pdfgrep cannot search yet display with xpdf?
I am on a Chromebook running Debian with pdfgrep v2.1.2. I have a PDF file of the full Mueller Report that I occasionally want to search for particular references.  Pdfgrep of the file for any pattern quickly returns nothing.  Pdftotext cannot seem to handle it and produces a very short file of junk.  Pdfinfo produces the following:
Title:           
Creator:         RICOH MP C6502
Producer:        RICOH MP C6502
CreationDate:    Wed Apr 17 15:23:21 2019 PDT
ModDate:         Wed Apr 17 15:59:41 2019 PDT
Custom Metadata: no
Metadata Stream: yes
Tagged:          no
UserProperties:  no
Suspects:        no
Form:            AcroForm
JavaScript:      no
Pages:           448
Encrypted:       no
Page size:       792 x 612 pts (letter)
Page rot:        270
File size:       145509756 bytes
Optimized:       yes
PDF version:     1.6

Could pdfgrep not be compatible with the PDF version of the file?

Since it was produced by a multi-function printer, the PDF likely only contains scanned images of the report. Without OCR (which a printer won’t do), it wouldn’t contain any text for pdftotext or pdfgrep to process.
Graphical PDF viewers are perfectly happy displaying images, so they wouldn’t have any difficulty displaying the PDF in question.

Also, the huge file size of 145 MB is a good indicator that the PDF file is full of images - in this case it contains only images and no text at all.

@rexkogitans I hesitated to add that as a heuristic, because many large PDFs are still searchable — they include both the scanned images and the text.

Thanks.  Is there any way of telling if a PDF has searchable text via (say) PDFinfo?  I mean is it a different type of file?

On looking for google public listings of recent sources of the official Mueller Report. I find 2 official volumes and one "full" one per the source question. The total number of pages is identical, however the files seem newer, are better produced and presented Sec508 tagged as accessibility searchable.

The redacted version of the Report on the Investigation into Russian Interference in the 2016 Presidential Election was released to the public by the Department of Justice on April 18, 2019.

File: report_volume1.pdf
File Size: 23.28 MB (24,409,776 Bytes)
Title: Report on the Investigation into Russian Interference in the 2016 Presidential Election - Volume 1
Subject: Investigation into Russian Interference in the 2016 Presidential Election
Author: Special Counsel’s Office
Created: 2020-11-02 15:22:45
Modified: 2022-02-02 14:17:18
PDF Producer: Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 20 Paper Capture Plug-in
PDF Version: 1.7
Fast Web View No
PDF Optimizations: Tagged PDF
Number of Pages: 207
Page Size: 21.59 x 27.94 cm (Letter)

File: report_volume2.pdf
File Size: 4.4 MB (4,610,644 Bytes)
Title: Report on the Investigation into Russian Interference in the 2016 Presidential Election - Volume 2
Subject: Investigation into Russian Interference in the 2016 Presidential Election
Author: Special Counsel’s Office
Created: 2019-05-06 18:43:27
Modified: 2020-06-19 14:59:27
PDF Producer: Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 19 Paper Capture Plug-in
PDF Version: 1.7
Fast Web View No
PDF Optimizations: Tagged PDF
Number of Pages: 187
Page Size: 21.59 x 27.94 cm (Letter)

from the https://www.justice.gov and available as
report_volume1.pdf
report_volume2.pdf
A version of combined report includes Appendices A-D thus a total 448 pages as per OP but with a different set of MetaData?
You will need to compare with "full" to see what other page contents may have been added or redacted ?
For example on page 9 of Vol 1 near the top we see Special Counsel’s work, he . . . shall provide the Attorney General a confidential report
The Files seem like a different description to the OP copy and thus as produced later, there may be discrepancies between the contents.
A larger and earlier "Scanned" and digitally signed copy seems to be https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-SCREPORT-MUELLER/pdf/GPO-SCREPORT-MUELLER.pdf and variations of that may be the cause of restricted  search due to encryption.

Thank you.  That's a very thorough analysis.  I'm going to pick up one of the more recent files.
